# Letter combinations of a phone keypad key

Tags: javascript, recursion, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I have a question about letter combinations of a phone keypad key in JavaScript. I wrote a solution using DFS recursion. But it does not work as expected. I am new to JavaScript but similarly written code in Ruby works.

The problem is about getting all possible letter combination from a phone keypad.

Input: "23"

Output: ["ad", "ae", "af", "bd", "be", "bf", "cd", "ce", "cf"].

With the code below, it stops at "af". Output is ["ad", "ae", "af"]. I am not sure why this code does not move to the second letter of "2", which is "b".

```js
const map = {
  "2": ["a", "b", "c"],
  "3": ["d", "e", "f"],
  "4": ["g", "h", "i"],
  "5": ["j", "k", "l"],
  "6": ["m", "n", "o"],
  "7": ["p", "q", "r", "s"],
  "8": ["t", "u", "v"],
  "9": ["w", "x", "y", "z"]
};

let result = [];

let letterCombinations = function(digits) {
  if (digits.length == 0) {
    return []
  };

  let stack = [];
  dfs(digits.split(''), 0, stack)

  return result
};

function dfs(digits, index, stack) {
  const currentLetters = map[digits[index]]

  for (i = 0; i < currentLetters.length; i++) {
    stack.push(currentLetters[i])

    if (index == digits.length - 1) {
      result.push(stack.join(''))
      stack.pop()
    } else {
      dfs(digits, index + 1, stack)
      stack.pop()
    }
  }
}

console.log(letterCombinations("23"));
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to declare `i` in your for loop otherwise it's global and keeps getting incremented on each recursion step.

Use `for (let i = 0; i < currentLetters.length; i++)`

```js
const map = {
  "2": ["a", "b", "c"],
  "3": ["d", "e", "f"],
  "4": ["g", "h", "i"],
  "5": ["j", "k", "l"],
  "6": ["m", "n", "o"],
  "7": ["p", "q", "r", "s"],
  "8": ["t", "u", "v"],
  "9": ["w", "x", "y", "z"]
};

let result = [];

let letterCombinations = function(digits) {
  if (digits.length == 0) {
    return []
  };

  let stack = [];
  dfs(digits.split(''), 0, stack)

  return result
};

function dfs(digits, index, stack) {
  const currentLetters = map[digits[index]]
  
  // declare the loop variable!
  for (let i = 0; i < currentLetters.length; i++) {
    stack.push(currentLetters[i])

    if (index == digits.length - 1) {
      result.push(stack.join(''))
      stack.pop()
    } else {
      dfs(digits, index + 1, stack)
      stack.pop()
    }
  }
}

console.log(letterCombinations("23"));
```

Comment: Wow thanks so much! Is declaration of i pretty much the norm when writing a for loop in JS?

Comment: Yes, @YoungsunPaik, you almost always want to declare it so you don't pollute the global space and so don't share it between loops.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a less complex implementation. I hope you find it useful!

```js
const map = {
  "2": ["a", "b", "c"],
  "3": ["d", "e", "f"],
  "4": ["g", "h", "i"],
  "5": ["j", "k", "l"],
  "6": ["m", "n", "o"],
  "7": ["p", "q", "r", "s"],
  "8": ["t", "u", "v"],
  "9": ["w", "x", "y", "z"]
};

function letterCombinations(digits) {
  digits = digits.split('');
  
  const firstArray = map[digits[0]];
  const secondArray = map[digits[1]];
  const result = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++)
  {
    for (let j = 0; j < secondArray.length; j++)
    {
      result.push(firstArray[i] + secondArray[j]);
    }
  }
  
  return result;
};

console.log(letterCombinations("23"));
```

Comment: It's less complex because, unlike the OP's code, it only works for input of exactly two numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const DailNumbers = {
  2: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  3: ['d', 'e', 'f'],
  4: ['g', 'h', 'i'],
  5: ['j', 'k', 'l'],
  6: ['m', 'n', 'o'],
  7: ['p', 'q', 'r', 's'],
  8: ['t', 'u', 'v'],
  9: ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z'],
}


const LoopNum =(arg, TeleNumbers)=>{
  
  // Number to String conversion and splitting the values
  let splitnum = arg.toString().split("");
  
  // If No values Just pass empty array
  if(splitnum.length < 1) return []
  
  const combinedArray = splitnum.map( (val) => TeleNumbers[val]);
  const temp = []; 
  
   // combined array is greater than one value
  if (combinedArray [1]) {
      for(let i = 0; i < combinedArray[0].length; i++){  
        for(let j = 0; j < combinedArray[1].length; j++){
          temp.push(combinedArray[0][i] +""+ combinedArray[1][j])
        }
      }
    }
  
  // combined array is greater than one value
  else {
    for(let i = 0; i < combinedArray[0].length; i++){    
          temp.push(combinedArray[0][i])
      } 
  }

  return temp
}
console.log(LoopNum('23', DailNumbers)) 

// result will ["ad", "ae", "af", "bd", "be", "bf","cd", "ce", "cf"]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Code-only answers are not nearly as useful as ones that also include some explanatory text.  Please [edit] to add more context.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Letter combination of a phone number(keypad key) Javascript Solution**

> Create a phone keypad dictionary first.
>
> Combine each digit from the dictionary array using nested loops.

```
/**
 * @param {string} digits "23"
 * @return {string[]} ["ad","ae","af","bd","be","bf","cd","ce","cf"]
 */
var letterCombinations = function(digits) {
    let tel = {
        2:['a','b','c'],
        3:['d','e','f'],
        4:['g','h','i'],
        5:['j','k','l'],
        6:['m','n','o'],
        7:['p','q','r','s'],
        8:['t','u','v'],
        9:['w','x','y','z']
    }, arr1=tel[digits[0]],arr2=tel[digits[1]],array=[];
    if(!digits.trim().length){
        return [];
    }
    if(digits.length == 1){
        return tel[digits];
    }
    for(let d=0;d<digits.length-1;d++) {
        arr1 = array.length ? array : tel[digits[d]];
        arr2 = tel[digits[d+1]];
        if(array.length){
            array =[];
        }
        if(digits[d+1]) {
            for(let i=0;i<arr1.length;i++) {
                for(let j=0;j<arr2.length;j++) {
                    array.push(arr1[i]+arr2[j])
                }
            }
        } else {
            return array;
        }

    }
    return array;
    
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this old question has been resurrected, here's an easier recursive version:

```js
const allNbrs = (chars) => ([c, ...cs]) =>
  c == undefined
    ? ['']
    : allNbrs (chars) (cs) .flatMap (s => (chars [c] || [c]) .map (c => c + s))

const tel = {2: ['a', 'b', 'c'], 3: ['d', 'e', 'f'], 4: ['g', 'h', 'i'], 5: ['j', 'k', 'l'], 6: ['m', 'n', 'o'], 7: ['p', 'q', 'r', 's'], 8: ['t', 'u', 'v'], 9: ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z']}

const letterCombinations = allNbrs (tel)

console .log (letterCombinations ('23'))
```

We separate the first letter of the string (`c`) from the remaining ones (`cs`), recur on those remaining ones, then, for every result, we combine it with each entry from our table (`chars`).

Note that `(chars || [c]) .map (...)` is used for those cases in which the character supplied is no in our table.  We could alternately do `(chars || []) .map (...)`, which would return an empty array if we had any bad characters.  Just `chars .map (...)` would throw an error if passed a zero.  I prefer the version above, as it gives an interesting answer for, say, `304`:

```js
letterCombinations ('304')
//=> ["d0w","e0w","f0w","d0x","e0x","f0x","d0y","e0y","f0y","d0z","e0z","f0z"]
```